# Order jQuery Droppable Elements By Having Last Dropped Item First

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, droppable

I did some searching and couldn't find an answer to this, plus did some messing around with the code to no avail. I have a standard jQuery UI draggable and droppable setup which works.

However when items (in this case shoes) are dragged into the droppable target area, they appear to be appended, so old items stay at the front and new items get added on the end and pushed out of view.

Is there a way of having the sortable items prepend to my target droppable as opposed to being appended?

Edit **

```
var proto = $.ui.droppable.prototype;

proto._create = function() {

    console.log('Calling the create method');

    var o = this.options, accept = o.accept;
    this.isover = 0; this.isout = 1;

    this.accept = $.isFunction(accept) ? accept : function(d) {
    return d.is(accept);
    };

    //Store the droppable's proportions
    this.proportions = { width: this.element[0].offsetWidth, height: this.element[0].offsetHeight };

    // Add the reference and positions to the manager
    $.ui.ddmanager.droppables[o.scope] = $.ui.ddmanager.droppables[o.scope] || [];
    $.ui.ddmanager.droppables[o.scope].unshift(this);

    (o.addClasses && this.element.addClass("ui-droppable"));
};
```

Comment: With draggable and droppable, you are in control of what action is taken on `drop`. You mention sortable--Is that the widget you're using? Any chance you could post some code?

Comment: Hi Andy, not really any code to post I am afraid. I'm basically asking how to make elements in jQuery UI droppable component prepend, rather than append. AlienWebGuy has posted an excellent answer and I just need to know how to override the _create method in jQuery UI now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, though it's pretty complicated. You'll need to extend the JQueryUI `ui.droppable` object modifying the `_create` function. Currently it uses push to add your new item to the end of the array, like so:

`$.ui.ddmanager.droppables[o.scope].push(this);`

You'll want to use unshift:

`$.ui.ddmanager.droppables[o.scope].unshift(this);`

JQuery droppable source:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.droppable.js

JavaScript `unshift()` documentation:http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp

Tutorial for extending JQueryUI widgets: http://bililite.com/blog/extending-jquery-ui-widgets/

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. How would I go about overriding the core _create method as I am including the entire jQuery UI library from Google CDN?

Comment: Check out that last link I posted which describes how to extend the UI widgets. You don't need to touch the master code, simply override the functionality :)

Comment: I'll update my question with some code I am using. For some reason overriding droppable doesn't appear to be working for me. I'm sure it's something simple I am doing wrong! Thank you for your patience and help.

Comment: Okay, I'm making a little more headway with this. But I am starting to think that the _create method isn't the right one. It doesn't appear to be called when items are dropped onto the droppables area. The items are being placed, but the _create method isn't called (console.log proved this). I've updated my question with the code I am currently using, but need to find the proper method where it appends the items or clones them.

Comment: @Dwayne what function was being triggered if it wasn't _create?